# $r^2\cos\theta+2ar\sin^2{\theta\over2}-a^2$ where $a>0$

Tags: polar-coordinates, plane-curves

What does the following equation represent?

$r^2\cos\theta+2ar\sin^2{\theta\over2}-a^2$ where $a>0$

My approach: I factorized the equation and it became $(a+r\cos\theta)(a-r)=0$

I feel that since $(a-r)$ is a factor, $\therefore$ one of the curve is a straight line. But, what is the other curve? Is it a circle? Then, how?

Comment: $r=a$ is the equation of a circle, and $r=-a/\cos \theta$ is a vertical line, for $x=r \cos\theta = -a$ and $y=r \sin \theta = -a \tan \theta$.

Comment: I couldn't understand. How is r=a is the equation of a circle?

Comment: If $r=a$ is the equation of a curve in polar coordinates, it means that the radius (measured from the origin) is a constant $a$, for all angle $\theta$. If $a>0$, I fear it must be a circle. Maybe you should have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), if you don't know very well what *polar coordinates* mean.